# Python to Get Windows Scheduled Tasks Status

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, scheduled-tasks

I have a Windows scheduled task which does some database updates and it runs every few hours.

I have a Python script which updates data in the same database, and it is called by the users.

I want to prevent data conflict between the scheduled task and Python script. When a user calls the Python script, how can I check if the scheduled task is running, so that the Python script delays updating the database until the scheduled task is finished? Or would it be easier to check if the database is being updated (how would I do this in Python script?)?

I am running Python 2.7 64-bit, Windows Server 2012 64-bit and SQLServer 2012 64-bit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid touching the database while in an unfinished state? Checking if a task is running will not solve that problem. Try looking up database transactions to solve this.

Comment: Both the scheduled task and Python script update tables A, B and C. In the Python script, I want to say: "If tables A, B and C are currently being updated by the scheduled task, then wait until it finishes."... the tables should be in a finished state at the point when the Python script is about to insert/update/delete.

Comment: You can use the [Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) COM interface. [`ITaskService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example: `import win32com.client;` `scheduler = win32com.client.Dispatch("Schedule.Service");` `scheduler.Connect();` `tasks = scheduler.GetRunningTasks(1);` `names = [tasks.Item(i+1).Name for i in range(tasks.Count)]`.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have worked.

Answer (score 1):

The function below will check the status from a Windows sheduled Task.

```py
def winTaskStat(task, bln=False):
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    prc = Popen(["powershell", '-Command',
                 '&{Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath \* | where taskname -eq "' + task + '" | select state;}'],
                stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    out, err = prc.communicate()
    if out == b'':
        print('Task ; ' + task + ' ; inexistent')
        if bln:
            return False
        else:
            return ''
    else:
        out = out.split(b'\r\n')
        res = []
        for it in out:
            if not it == b'':
                res.append(it.decode('utf-8').strip().lower())
        if bln:
            rd = {'disabled': False, 'ready': True}
            return rd[res[-1]]
        else:
            return res[-1]
```

To check the Scheduled Task Status with "if" call as follow:

```py
task = 'task_to_check'
if winTaskStat(task, bln=True):
    print(task + ' is <Enabled>')
else:
    print(task + ' is <Disabled>')
```

Or just return the Task status, call as follow:

```py
task = 'task_to_check'
print(winTaskStat(task))
```